# kubernetese Nginx Ingress TCP Mariadb service not able to connect

Tags: nginx-ingress

I am trying to expose Mariadb deployment using Nginx ingress.

Some of the references that I had look at so far, but could not resolve my problem are as follows.

1. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md
2. [Why ingress-nginx controller tcp-services not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223163/why-ingress-nginx-controller-tcp-services-not-working)
3. [Kubernetes 1.16 Nginx Ingress (0.26.1) TCP Mariadb/MySQL service not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252103/kubernetes-1-16-nginx-ingress-0-26-1-tcp-mariadb-mysql-service-not-working)
4. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

When I use nodeport instead of nginx ingress, I am able to connect.

But when I use nginx ingress, I am not able to connect.

I use the following three commands to get the port number of nginx controller.

```
INGRESSNODEPORTIP=$(kubectl get ingresses mariadb-ingress -o jsonpath='{ .status.loadBalancer.ingress[].ip }')
NODEPORT=$(kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller -o jsonpath='{ .spec.ports[?(@.name=="http")].nodePort }')
echo $INGRESSNODEPORTIP:$NODEPORT
```

I get the following ip and port.

```
162.187.99.102:31358
```

And when I try to connect, as you can see, it does not connect.

[image: Not able to connect to maria db]
What am I missing?

My manifests are as follows.

First the deployment manifest.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mariadb-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      appmariadbpods: ohr-maria-db-pods
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        appmariadbpods: ohr-maria-db-pods
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: "ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD"
          value: "true"
        - name: MARIADB_DATABASE
          value: bitnami_orangehrm
        - name: MARIADB_USER
          value: bn_orangehrm
        image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3
        name: mariadb-container
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
          name: mariadb-data
      volumes:
      - name: mariadb-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: maria-db-pvc
```

The Persistent Volume is as follows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: maria-db-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: 162.187.99.200
    path: "/export/volumes/ohr-maria-db"
```

The Persistent Volume Claim is as follows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: maria-db-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

The service is as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ohr-maria-db-service-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    appmariadbpods: ohr-maria-db-pods
  ports:
  - name: ohr-maria-db-ingress
    port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
```

The config map.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  3306: "default/ohr-maria-db-service-ingress:3306"
```

Finally the ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mariadb-ingress
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
        name: ohr-maria-db-service # hello-world-service-default
        port: 
            number: 3306
```

The nginx controller is deployed using the [deploy file here.](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy/static/provider/baremetal)

```
kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml
```

What baffles me is when I use nodeport, the service would instead look like this and this works!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ohr-maria-db-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    appmariadbpods: ohr-maria-db-pods
  ports:
  - name: ohr-maria-db-nodeport
    port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 30011
```

Why is my nginx ingress does not work? This is driving me nuts, any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574104/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-on-nodeport

Answer (score 1):

if you check the node port which you got from the nginx is

```
162.187.99.102:31358
```

port is **31358** can you please let me know mapping when the request comes on ingress should go to Database?

while for the service, there is a direct mapping of the port number you can see **target port** and **port**.

also, command you are firing

```
INGRESSNODEPORTIP=$(kubectl get ingresses mariadb-ingress -o jsonpath='{ .status.loadBalancer.ingress[].ip }')
```

this will be giving the LoadBalancer IP I think that load Balancer will be HTTP load balancer by default.

```
NODEPORT=$(kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller -o jsonpath='{ .spec.ports[?(@.name=="http")].nodePort }')
```

this is the node port you are getting but Node will only work with IP of slave nodes or work node not with the Load balancer that ingress has created.

```
echo $INGRESSNODEPORTIP:$NODEPORT
```